# Flashing Actionbar Icon

Tags: android

I have an ActionBar icon which is a button to a chat message screen. I have two copies of the icon. One standard grey, and one yellow.

When I display the yellow icon to indicate there is a message waiting, I want it to flash slowly.

Is this possible with an actionbar icon?

Comment: When you say 'icon' what do you mean? What portion of the Actionbar is this sitting in? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: The standard actionbar menu icons (or button or menu item. Whichever is the correct term) on the right hand side of the actionbar.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [setIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setIcon%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) method of the MenuItem. Since it takes a Drawable you could use an [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) to achieve your slow flash effect.

Comment: Good suggestion, but unfortunately this does not work. I attempted to set an AnimationDrawable to a MenuItem, and started the animation in the onCreateOptionsMenu(). I think the only way to go about it is to create a custom ActionProvider class which is a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

I probably did this a dodgy way as I'm quite new to Android but maybe it will help someone / someone will correct me.

I've got a 500ms timer that executes periodically which runs "invalidateOptionsMenu();" this will cause the menu to be redrawn, once this happens you simply hide / show your icon inside, below I'm flashing a 'no signal' icon. Just set your timer to whatever flash period you want.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    if(!AppStates.InternetAvailable || !AppStates.ServerContactable)
    {
        if(!NoSignalFlashState) NoSignalFlashState=true;
        else NoSignalFlashState=false;
        menu.findItem(R.id.ActionNoSignal).setVisible(NoSignalFlashState);
    }
    else menu.findItem(R.id.ActionNoSignal).setVisible(false);

   super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    return true;
}
```