# Icon in ActionBar blinking

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, toolbar

I want to create an Action Bar for my app that displays a blinking logo. I want to display the image every two seconds and when the image hides, display the fragment title.

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.logo_nuevo);

       /* getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo_nuevo); */

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        nvDrawer.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
```

Comment: Put some code what you did

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320580/flashing-actionbar-icon